# how to get all the data from an association with sequelize

Tags: mysql, sequelize.js

For instance we have TABLE `A`, `B`, `C`, and `D` but `A`, `B`, and `D` are associated, but `C` is only associated with `B`.

```
TABLE A
| id | B_id | D_id 

TABLE B
| id | C_id | total | transaction |

TABLE C
| id | firstname | lastname |

TABLE D
| id | price | brand |
```

How can i get all the data for `B`, `C` and `D` together in one table with association using sequelize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a `Model` for table `A` and then use the `associate()` function to relate it to the `models.B` and `models.D` tables. The definition for table `B` would then relate it to table `A` as its parent and table `C` as its child. Table `C` only defines table `B` as its parent. Finally table `D` is related back to table `A`

```js
// create models for each of the tables.
// this can be in different files and use a loader, etc

const ModelA = sequelize.define(
  'A',
  { /* ...field definition */ }
);

const ModelB = sequelize.define(
  'B',
  { /* ...field definition */ }
);

const ModelC = sequelize.define(
  'C',
  { /* ...field definition */ }
);

const ModelD = sequelize.define(
  'D',
  { /* ...field definition */ }
);
```

Now create associations between the different models.

```js
// Table A to B and D
ModelA.hasOne(ModelB);
ModelA.hasOne(ModelD);

// Table B to A (parent) and C (child)
ModelB.belongsTo(ModelA);
ModelB.hasOne(ModelC);

// Table C to B (parent)
ModelC.belongsTo(ModelB);

// Table D to A (parent)
ModelD.belongsTo(ModelA);
```

Now you can create a query to get all the related data.

```js
const result = await ModelA.findAll({
  include: [ // use an array to relate to multiple tables
    {
      model: ModelB,
      include: { // we can use an object since we are only relating one table
        model: ModelC,
      },
    },
    {
      model: ModelD,
    },
  ],  
});
```